# ypcat passwd returns error with NIS

Tags: nis

I have set up and installed NIS server on my Ubuntu platform Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

It all is going well and ive followed these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo), ive added a user and all seems to be good, however when logged in a  root I get the following error

```
# ypcat passwd
No such map passwd.byname. Reason: No such map in server's domain
```

Any ideas on how to get around this error

Comment: Try [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nis-client-problem-469545/), it could help.